# Markov/Chebyshev's inequality Problems

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables for which $ E(X)=75 $,
>   $ E(Y)=75 $, $\mathrm{var}(X)=10$, $\mathrm{var}(Y)=12$,
>   $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=-3$
>
> - (i) Find and upper bound to $P(|X-Y| \ge 15)$.
> - (ii) Let $Z$ be a random variable with mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. By applying Markov's inequality to the random variable
>     $W=(Z+t)^2$, $t>0$, show that:
>
> $$P(Z \ge a) \le \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}, \mathrm{\ \ \ for\ \ any \ \ } a>0$$
>
> - (iii) Hence find an upper bound to $P(X \ge Y + 15)$.

How do you compute part (iii)?

I am not sure on how to compute var(X-Y), which formula do you use ?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint for (i): Compute the mean and the variance of X-Y.

Comment: @Did: for part i could you please confirm if the answer is 28/225 ?

Comment: I have improved the question.

Answer (score 2):

For part (i), let's denote $Z=X-Y$, then we have
$$E(Z) = E(X) - E(Y) = 0$$

and

$$Var(Z) = Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2Cov(X,Y) = 28$$

Hence, applying Chebyshev's inequality we obtain

$$ P(|Z-E(Z)|\ge 15) \le \frac{Var(Z)}{15^2} = \frac{28}{225}$$

For part (iii), you can apply Markov's inequality with the condition that $Z$ is an non-negative random variable (not mentioned in assumption).

Comment: for part iii, is the answer 28/253 ? Please confirm. :)

Comment: I'm not sure, if $Z=X-Y$ is non-negative, apply Markov's inequality $P(X-Y \ge 15) \le E(Z)/15=0$.

Comment: In part (ii), are you sure the upper bound is $\sigma^2/(\sigma^2 + a^2)$? I think that it must be $(\sigma^2 + a^2)/a^2$.